# Dynamic accodion panel passing variable in ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I want to pass variable to bean method on tabClose and tabChange- i want to pass index of the tab that i clicked.

```
<p:accordionPanel id="layerListAccordionPanel" multiple="true" activeIndex="#{layersModelMock.activeIndex}" value="#{layersModelMock.layerCategories}" var="category">
    <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{layersController.deselectCategory(category.id)}" />
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{layersController.selectCategory(category.id)}" />

    <p:tab id="layerPanel" title="#{category.name}" closable="true">
        Test
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

When i test code above i alwayes pass '0'. I don't know how to get index of the tab and pass it through ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/accordionPanelEvents.jsf) you can use tab change as event in your bean

```
 public void onTabClose(TabCloseEvent event) {  
    deselectCategory(event.getTab().getId());
}  

 public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {  
    selectCategory(event.getTab().getId());
}
```

You'll need to adapt your XHTML accordingly.

```
<p:accordionPanel id="layerListAccordionPanel" multiple="true" activeIndex="#{layersModelMock.activeIndex}" value="#{layersModelMock.layerCategories}" var="category">
    <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{layersController.onTabChange}" />
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{layersController.onTabClose}" />

    <p:tab id="#{category.id}" title="#{category.name}" closable="true">
        Test
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Haven't tested it myself but according to Primefaces homepage it should work.

**Edit**

Tested - works.